# How to compile a Mono program for Raspberry Pi Zero on Windows?

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, mono, raspberry-pi-zero

I want to be able to compile a c# console app with Mono so that it will run on the Raspberry Pi Zero.  I want to do it on my Windows machine.  And after I'd like to copy/ssh the binary to the Pi Zero and just run it.

I've already done the following:

1. Mono runtime is already installed on the Pi Zero.
2. I can compile it directly on the Pi Zero and it works fine, but it's slow and, consequently, so is the dev cycle.

Is it possible or am I required to use the Mono toolchain on the destination box?

Comment: If you compile for "Any CPU" on your desktop, you should be able to ssh, copy deploy, and run it...

Answer (score 2):

If your Pi Zero is all set up, then just compiling on your Windows machine with "Any CPU" setting (rather than targeting x86/x64) should do the trick, as it's just IL at that point; it gets JITted on the Pi by the Mono runtime to ARM assembly.